# Static Class Method in Immediate Window

Tags: c#, immediate-window

If I have a class `FilePathHandler` which has a static method `FormatSubPath` and I breakpoint in my code is there a way to call this method either in the immediate window or watch window?

Usage;

```
var temp = FilePathHandler.FormatSubPath(path);
```

If I write the above in the Immediate window to test something on the fly during a breakpoint, I get the error "error CS0103: The name 'FilePathHandler' does not exist in the current context". Is there anyway to do this or is it not possible?

Comment: Have you tried using with its complete namespace? i.e NameSpace.FilePathHandler.FormatSubPath(path);

Comment: Try using the full namespace: `FullNamespace.Thing.Whatever.FilePathHandler.FormatSubPath()`

Comment: instead of immediate window .. use quick watch window

Comment: @IpsitGaur Yup, that did the job. Want to submit as an answer?

Comment: @windowskm Thanks!!, do the honor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using with its complete namespace? i.e `NameSpace.FilePathHandler.FormatSubPath(path);`

Comment: Perfect, didn't realise I needed the namespace. Thanks!